# use AForm in a subsite Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod, yesod-forms

I want create a subsite to all CRUD operation in my project, I have the following code

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances     #-}

module Demo (
   module Demo.Data,
   module Demo
   )where

import Data.Maybe   (Maybe)


import Demo.Data
import Yesod
import Prelude (IO,($))

import Model
import Crud.FormsC


getDemoNewR :: Yesod master => HandlerT YesodDemo (HandlerT master IO) Html
getDemoNewR = do 
           (widget, encoding) <- generateFormPost $ renderBootstrap3 BootstrapBasicForm $ demoForm  Nothing
           defaultLayout $ do                        
                $(widgetFile "Exam/createExam")
```

but have this error  `Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Handler’`

I can't import the Foundation  because generate a cycle reference because I have a import Demo in my Foundation.hs

```
import Demo
import Demo.Data 

data App = App
{ appSettings    :: AppSettings
, appStatic      :: Static -- ^ Settings for static file serving.
, appConnPool    :: ConnectionPool -- ^ Database connection pool.
, appHttpManager :: Manager
, appLogger      :: Logger
, getDemo        :: YesodDemo
}
```

so what have import to use Handler o how I create a subSite?

Comment: Generic advice: google "hs-boot" files, or restructure your module hierarchy. If you want more specific advice, please give us a minimal but complete code sample that causes that error.

Comment: Assuming you're building off of the scafolding site, the `Handler` type alias is generated inside Foundation.hs from `mkYesodData`.

Comment: Hi thanks for their answers I add the code detail and the beginning to my foundation.hs, maybe someone have a example to a subSite different to the chat that have in a book

Answer (score 2):

When you are in a SubSite use `(HandlerT master IO)`